# Ionic 3 commands not working

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm new in Ionic, recently i got an error with every command i write for ionic, I'm using `ionic 3.18.0` 
Here's the error:

```
{  Error
at new Exception 
(C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-
utils\lib\errors.js:8:23)
    at new FatalException 
(C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-
utils\lib\errors.js:17:9)
    at Config.<anonymous> 
(C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-
utils\lib\config.js:61:35)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected 
(C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\tslib\
 tslib.js:101:69)
    at <anonymous> name: 'Exception', exitCode: 1, fatal: true }
```

Hope you can help me, i have no idea whats wrong, i try to install again ionic, i delete the `npm_modules` folder in `/users/luis/AppData/Roaming/` even i reinstall node, i dont know what to do

Comment: What is the example of "every command"? Can you do `ionic help`?

Comment: Ionic serve, ionic help even only ionic

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on based on error messages alone. Maybe you have an older version of typescript? I don't know. But, still maybe you want to try `npm i -g typescript@latest` and see if it helps? If it doesn't, try downgrading ionic `npm i -g ionic@3.16.0` (for instance). Not much I can see from the error message...

Comment: I have tried that, it's still the same, i know the error message doesnt help, but it's all it display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by: unistalling Node.js, deleting node_modules/ and installing the last version of Node.js.

Don't know what was wrong, but it solve all.